# Custom Location Services with external GPS connected to Raspberry Pi with android things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, gps, android-gps, android-things

Hello I am wanting to connect an external GPS unit via I2C or serial to a raspberry pi 3 running android things to have this GPS unit provide location data.

So far using the Rasbarian OS I have a working python script with custom libraries. The script outputs raw NMEA data.

I am wondering how would I need to run this script to be able to have Android Location services use this data for location services? Would I need to create an app using the location services API? Or since this is a locally installed device would I need to write firmware or some kind? I am just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of what kind of software I would need to write (an app or driver or firmware) in order to have this NMEA data accessible for location services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of GPS driver connected via serial port you can find in [Android Things user-space GPS driver](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps) and how to use it you can find in [UART GPS sample for Android Things](https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/gps). Also take a look at [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/location) and examples like [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-things-understanding-and-writing-drivers--cms-28088).